# Which concurrency construct to use for running multiple background tasks when the app is paused for Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service

I'm trying to implement multiple tasks in my app that are required to continue running even when the app is paused (when the app loses focus but the user has not completely closed the app).

The first task consists of establishing a connection to a server and receiving updates.
The second task consists of communicating back and forth with a paired Bluetooth device.

Both tasks will **not** only be ran when the app is paused, they will be required to be run when the app is in focus. When the app is in focus they will be required to update the GUI based on the information they receive. Also both tasks task doesn't really have a set finishing condition except for when the user decides to stop the tasks themselves or when the app is completely closed thus they must be able to be cancelled in mid process. These two tasks will very likely be running for a long time.

In summary:

- Two background tasks that can be run when app is not in focus.
- Both tasks are required to be able to update the GUI when the app is in focus.
- Both tasks must be able to be terminated when the user decides to stop the task inside the app or when the app is completely closed.

I believe that I need to using either a **Service, IntentService or AsyncTask.**
From my reading I believe that I should be using an AsyncTask but I want to be sure before starting.

**Service**: Can't manipulate GUI.
**IntentService**: Can't run tasks in parallel, they will be queued on the same thread.
**AsyncTask**: Seems fine!

Is this correct or should I be using a combination of things somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the point of Service and IntentService.  They are not a concurrency mechanism.  They will not run automatically in the background.  They run on the same thread as your app.  If you need concurrency, you need either AsyncTask or Thread.  Please note that if you use AsyncTask to get true concurrency between multiple tasks you still need to use executeOnExecutor().

What Services do is persist even when your Activity is gone, or when it isn't in the foreground anymore (either another activity in your app is, or another app is).  So if you need your secondary thread to be running after the Activity is finished, you should have it owned in a Service.  If you don't, owning it in the Activity is fine.

An IntentService is basically a Service that does more or less fixed length jobs 1 at a time.  There's uses for them, but if they need to do network IO or anything like that they still have to spin off AsyncTasks, because they still are run on the main thread.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. 
So would I use a Service with two threads inside, one for each of my tasks?

Comment: That's definitely one way of doing it.  Basically it breaks down into two questions-  1)DO I need this to continue after my Activity is finish()ed?  If so, you need a service.  2)Is this something I want to run very occasionally or run constantly?  If occassionally use an AsyncTask, if constantly use a Thread.

Comment: I see. But how would I manipulate the GUI in the Service? I thought it wasn't possible to manipulate the GUI in a Service.

Comment: Its not, you'd inform your activity (either via a BroadcastReceiver, callback, or other method) and it would redraw itself.  Most AsyncTasks that effect the UI tend to be owned by the Activity itself,  although if the data is useful to multiple activities it isn't unusual to have a service own it

Answer (score -1):

You should use a service, the purpose of a service is to have a much lesser restricted lifecycle that can run while the app isn't in the foreground. You can use a BroadcastReceiver or callback/AIDL to send messages back to the calling activity that will manipulate the ui.